# Lit components do not automatically request an update on property change (problem only in my storybook)

Tags: lit-element, lit-html, lit

This is really odd: I'm using `lit` in a storybook (using `@storybook/html`).
I do not know why, but in my environment `lit` does not update the component automatically when a property has been changed. If I call `requestUpdate` explicitly, it is indeed updating.
This happens with every component, even this very simple demo component (shows 'waiting...' first, and after 3 seconds it should show 'done') ... working obviously in this codesandbox ... but not working in my storybook :-(
https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-river-087wz?file=/src/index.ts

Is there by any change anybody who might have an idea what could be the reason for this strange issue? TYVMIA

[EDIT]: This might be the reason:
https://lit.dev/msg/class-field-shadowing
You should use `"useDefineForClassFields": false` in tsconfig.json.
Actually I indeed had set it to `true`, but after changing to `false` I still have the above issue.

PS: I'm using the latest versions of lit (2.1.1) and storybook (6.4.13)

PPS: Removing directory `node_modules` and file `yarn.lock` and running `yarn install` did not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to edit Natacha response,

I have the same issue and the following fixed my issue

- In `tsconfig.json` add `"useDefineForClassFields": false,` in `compilerOptions`
- yarn add -D ts-loader@8.3.0
- Add the following to `.storybook/main.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  //...
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    //...
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Vince. I didn't know about that `webpackFinal` thingy .... that seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In `tsconfig.json` you have to set option `useDefineForClassFields` to `false` to make `lit` run properly. For more information please see
https://lit.dev/msg/class-field-shadowing .

To fully solve the issue with Storybook/Webpack I also had to do the following:

- `yarn add -D ts-loader@8.3.0` (version 9.x does not work with Webpack4)
- [EDIT: Please check Vince's answer below ... his solution (= main.js + webpackFinal) seems to be the preferred way]

  Adding the following to `.storybook/webpack.config.json` (not really sure why):

  ```
  config.module.rules.push({
     test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
     include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
     loader: require.resolve('ts-loader')
  })
  ```